# how to get function into my empty [ ]

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, template-engine

Hey I wrote out a function getNewId that returns a random number based on a timestamp 
I want to be able to get that number in an empty [ ]  so that when i inspect the element and look at the code it looks like this

name="locations[timestamp_from_function][street]"

here is the fiddle im working on
http://jsfiddle.net/d0okie0612/22cTn/

here is my html

```
   <div id="container">
   <div id="top_form">
   <form>
    Street: <input class="street" name="locations[][street]" id="form_element" type="text">  <br><br>
       City: <input class="city" name="locations[][city]" id="form_element" type="text">
      <select>
        <option value=" ">State</option>
        <option value="ca">CA</option>
        <option value="az">AZ</option>
        <option value="de">DE</option>
        </select>
        Zip: <input name="locations[][zipcode]" type="text"><br /><br />
     </form>
   </div>
  </div>

 <br />
 <a href="#" id="awsomeButton">+ Add Location</a>
  <br />
```

Submit

heres the script

```
     var tpl = ""
     + "<div id='location_div_<%= id %>'><h1>My Location #<%= id %></h1></div>";

      var newId = new Date().getTime();
      var template = _.template(tpl);
       var compiled = template({id: newId});

       var addedForm = "<div id='added_form'>"
         + "<a href='#' class='close_btn'>x</a>"
         + "Street: <input name='locations[][street]' type='text'>"
          + "<br /><br />"
           + "City: <input name='locations[][city]' type='text'>"
           + "<select>"
           + "<option value=' '>State</option>"
           + "</select>"
           + "Zip: <input name='locations[][zipcode]' type='text'>"
            + "</div>"


           function getNewId() {
           var newId = new Date().getTime();
           return newId;
             }

            var myArray = [];
            $('#awsomeButton').on('click', function(e) {
            $(addedForm).hide().appendTo('form').fadeIn('slow');

            });


           $('.close_btn').live('click', function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           $(this).parents('div#added_form:first').fadeOut('slow', function() {
          $(this).remove();    

        });
         });
```

I kinda think this should be easy but im at a lost please help

​
​

Comment: Irrelevant, but you spelt 'add location' wrong on the button

Comment: Why don't you just make it an underscore template, as you have done with `tpl`?

Comment: @BubbaWoop Well you spelled "spelled" wrong, so it seems we have a spelling police standoff :)

Comment: You say you want a random number based on the timestamp, but it seems you simply use the current timestamp. Thats not a random number.

Comment: your right i worded that wrong sorry i meant i just need the timestamp in there but for each form it should be a unique number

Comment: @MikeBrant it's English UK, not just a type of malt heh

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#added_form input[name^=locations\\[\\]]").each(function(input){
   var name = input.attr("name");
   var match = name.match(/^locations\[\]\[(.*)\]$/)
   if(match.length > 1) {
      var newName = "locations["+getNewId()+"]["+match[1]+"]";
      input.attr("name", newName);
   }
});
```